# How do I inherit from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

I want all the functionality of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` but I want it as `Foo<TKey,TValue>`.

**How should I go about doing this?**
Currently I am using

```
class Foo<TKey,TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{   
    /*
     I'm getting all sorts of errors because I don't know how to 
     overload the constructors of the parent class.
    */
    // overloaded methods and constructors goes here.

    Foo<TKey,TValue>():base(){}
    Foo<TKey,TValue>(int capacity):base(capacity){}

}
```

**What is the right way to overload constructors and methods of the parent class?**

***NOTE:I think I have misused the word 'overload' please correct it or suggest correction.***

Comment: You say (in the comment to my answer) that it is an implementation of the decorator pattern. Whatever it is exactly used for, I doubt that you should inherit from Dictionary, not even implement IDictionary. I think you should just write a regular class which holds a (private) dictionary to manage its state, and has some Add, Remove and Get kind of methods.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You were close, you just need to remove the type parameters from the constructors.

```
class Foo<TKey,TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{   
    Foo():base(){}
    Foo(int capacity):base(capacity){}
}
```

To override a method you can use the override keyword.

Comment: Not within the constructors, no... they're already within the type, so they already "have" the type parameters.

Comment: Nope, TKey and TValue are now defined as part of the class.  You don't need to redefine them in each method.

Comment: _and_ make them public, usually.

Comment: Sorry,I deleted the comment by accident.

Comment: How can I make them all public without writing public in front of each one?

Comment: public has to be explicitly defined in C#, without it everything defaults to private.

Comment: I guess then I will have to override each and every constructor of the base class explicitly or is there any other way ?

Comment: Not quote everything defaults to private: class, struct and enum default to internal, whereas methods, properties and fields default to private.

Comment: What is the point of inheriting from Dictionary if none of the methods are virtual?

Answer (score 19):

Not directly answering your question, just an advice. I would not inherit the dictionary, I would implement `IDictionary<T,K>` and aggregate a Dictionary. It is most probably a better solution:

```
class Foo<TKey,TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{   

    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> myDict;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: (+1) What do you recommend if I want to use just the Dictionary but with name Foo?

Comment: Why would you do this? A kind of C-style typedef?

Comment: That's a Decorator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Possible drawback: You need to implement each connection from your class to your member dictionary manually.

Comment: @Mao: that's true, you need to implement each method, but you also might find it practical to have full control.

Comment: @TheChairman FWIW, if you're using ReSharper, there's a very handy context action that delegates all `IDictionary` members to the `myDict` field (when fixing the "missing members" error). You can also press `alt`+`ins` and choose "Delegating members..." to insert them. Saves a lot of work!

Comment: In what sense is inheriting directly from a dictionary a bad solution?

Answer (score 10):

If you just want the same type but with a different name, you can shorten it with [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#example-1) alias:

```
using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
```

and then

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

Comment: This is true and will work. But unfortunately, Visual Studio does not provide good support for aliasing. Right-clicking `Foo` in the code and selecting "Go to Definition" will bring you to the definition of generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. And "Go to Declaration" seems plainly broken. Alas.